# Can I avoid a downcast here?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am working on a suite of code for numerical PDEs. Previously we had separate codes for problems in different dimensions, and many classes of objects that make up a mesh, e.g. Cell, Face, Edge, Vertex. I am trying to write a dimension independent code, and trying to write a base class that contains information for all the different types of mesh objects. This class is able to handle everything I need from Cell, Face etc, and implements procedures only depending on the dimension of the object, and the dimension of the space it is embedded in.

```
class MeshObject
{
 public:
      MeshObject(..., size_t base_dimension, size_t dimension);
     ...
 private:
     size_t _base_dimension;
     size_t _dimension;
     ...
     ...
}
```

However, so that the code is compatible with existing schemes we have, we will want to work with the derived classes. For example, a vertex has dimension 0 and we might have a line of code that looks like this

```
Vertex v = mesh->get_vertex(vertex_number); // Will now return a MeshObject with dimension = 0
```

I could achieve this by having Vertex be a class derived from MeshObject and performing a downcast:

```
class Vertex : public MeshObject
{
public:
     Vertex(..., size_t base_dimension) 
     : MeshObject(..., base_dimension, 0) {} // i.e. sets dimension to 0
}
```

and I could do this for all my different object types, and perform a down cast whenever necessary. However, I would like to avoid all the excessive downcasting. I would rather have something like

```
typedef MeshObject Vertex; // and somehow ensure that dimension = 0
```

Is there a simple way to implement the above? Or a way to avoid defining derived classes and down casting? Any thoughts on a solution or on my coding structure would be appreciated.

To add some clarity... perhaps... a Vertex is a MeshObject with _dimension = 0, an edge is a MeshObject with _dimension = 1, a Face is a MeshObject with _dimension = _base_dimension - 1, a Cell is a MeshObject with _dimension = _base_dimension, and finally, the mesh will be a vector of vectors of MeshObjects.

Comment: After I read this twice, I still don't understand.  Is `MeshObject` a _part_ of a mesh, like a Cell/Face/Vector, or is `MeshObject` a complete mesh that is made up of Cell/Face/Vector objects?  (You _should_ be doing the second one)

Comment: Nothing in your question here makes me think there's any need anywhere for base or derived classes.

Comment: @Mooing Duck Sorry, a mesh will be a vector of MeshObjects. I don't think I need derived classes either, but not sure what the solution is. Also, as you can probably tell I am a mathematician not a programmer

Comment: The solution is to have a mesh not be a vector of meshObjects. The mesh would usually _contain_  a vector of Faces and a vector of Vertices. I don't know what a "Cell" is here, but it might also contain a vector of those too. I think the concept of a MeshObject should be abandoned.

Comment: Yes. But depending on the dimension of the problem, a mesh might be a vector of edges and vertices, a vector of faces, edges and vertices, a vector of cells, faces, edges, and vertices,... etc. This could be a 10 dimensional problem theoretically. So to make it dimension independent a mesh is a vector of vectors of MeshObjects with each vector of objects having different dimension

Comment: `Vertex v = mesh->get_vertex(vertex_number);` - if your function is supposed to return `vertex`, then, you shouldn't **downcast**.

Comment: The function will return a MeshObject

Comment: "a mesh might be a vector of edges and vertices, a vector of faces, edges and vertices, a vector of cells, faces, edges, and vertices,... etc." Those don't sounds like they should be all the same Mesh class. It sounds like you have 3 separate Mesh classes. Two of those should have a `Vertex getVertex(int index)` method that returns a Vertex from their vector of Vertecies member.  None of this has _anything_ to do with dimensions

Comment: @MooingDuck it has everything to do with dimensions. The amount of different types of objects a mesh has is solely determined by the dimension of the mesh. If it is a 2D mesh then it has cells, edges and vertices. If it is an 8 dimensional mesh then it has 9 different types of MeshObjects, with dimension 8 through to 0.

Comment: @epiliam: I just saw your edit, I get it now, I had _completely_ misunderstood the problem!

Comment: Understandable, it was poorly asked

Comment: Actually, my last comment still applies. Those don't sounds like they should be all the same Mesh class. It sounds like you have 3 separate Mesh classes. Two of those should have a Vertex getVertex(int index) method that returns a Vertex from their vector of Vertecies member. For example: Your code appears to allow a Mesh to only contain `Vertexes`, with no edges or Faces. That's clearly invalid.

Comment: How do you mean 3 separate mesh classes? If I had a 364 dimensional mesh should I define a class just for that particular case? The whole point was to define a dimension independent mesh class so that we can generalise our codes to higher dimensions.

Comment: A mesh will be a vector of vectors of mesh objects. Each vector of mesh objects will correspond to a particular dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
 Vertex(..., size_t base_dimension) 
 : MeshObject(..., base_dimension, 0) {}
```

is not a downcast. It's just normal base class initialization. So, you want to make `Vertex` an alias for a zero-dimensional mesh, *without* having to write all the boilerplate?

You could write

```
template <size_t Dim>
class FixedDimensionMesh : public Mesh
{
public:
  FixedDimensionMesh(..., size_t base_dimension)
    : Mesh(..., base_dimension, Dim)
  {}
};

using Vertex = FixedDimensionMesh<0>;
using Edge = FixedDimensionMesh<1>;
// ... etc ...
```

so your intermediate template generates all the boilerplate for you.